# How do I keep a window on top in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, window-manager

In Windows 8, how do I keep a window above other windows, like the "Always On Top" option on many Linux desktops?

Related: [Is it possible to get the Ubuntu 'Always on top' functionality in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/105699/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ubuntu-always-on-top-functionality-in-windows)

DeskPins works in Windows 7, but not Windows 8.  Is there software for Windows 8 that provides "Always On Top" functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make window always on top?](http://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top), [Is it possible to get the Ubuntu 'Always on top' functionality in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/105699/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ubuntu-always-on-top-functionality-in-windows)

Comment: Just because the accepted answer doesn't work for you, doesn't mean it's a different question.  Please check out other answers and solutions offered as well.  If you need new/different/better answers, then please place a [Bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question instead of asking it again.

Answer (score 2):

In the question you link to, there's an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/352691/8691) that suggests using an Autohotkey script:

```
The program is written in Autohotkey with a single line of code:

^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

I can personally recommend this script as I've used it daily for years. Simply run it and press Ctrl+Space to toggle whether the window is always on top or not.

Plus it's really light on resources.

Original link to the download (from answer): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/149566/Downloads/always-on-top.zip

Comment: I have an executable (probably from that answer you linked) and it works fantastically.